# 500 Internal Server Error on Apache/PHP AddHandler wrapper

Tags: php, apache, addhandler

I'm trying to create a wrapper/handler that will be called on the Apache server whenever someone requests any PHP script inside of a directory.  That way I can authorize users for the entire directory or write some other stuff to be called when the directory is called.

This is the best configuration I've been able to come up with...

```
 <Directory "/srv/http/INNOV/PUBLIC_HTML/kb">
  Options -Indexes
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  DirectoryIndex index.php

  AddHandler auth_handler .php
  Action auth_handler /kb/auth_handler.php
 </Directory>
```

> [Wed Dec 01 12:28:06 2010] [error]
>   [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] Request
>   exceeded the limit of 10 internal
>   redirects due to probable
>   configuration error. Use
>   'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase
>   the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel
>   debug' to get a backtrace.

*Note: I didn't see anything in LogLevel debug.*

This is my handler (so far)... just trying to do an 'echo' or 'die' for now...

```
<?php
$FILE = $_SERVER['PATH_TRANSLATED'];
//readfile($FILE);
die($FILE);
?>
```

Also, please note, this is inside a virtualhost directive, but that shouldn't matter.  I also tried the 3rd parameter "virtual" option for the "Action" directive and same thing.

Does anybody know why it would do this?

Comment: @user471231 - Do you applied rewrite or redirect ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a guess - because the auth_handler script auth_handler.php lives inside the folder you're trying to handle, you're getting an infinite loop. That is, it recieves the php request, directs it to auth_hanlder which attempts to call auth_handler.php which then loads up the handler again, etc. Move auth_hanlder.php out of that folder and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Okay, apparently that was the issue.  I can't believe I was that stupid.